# Blackberry Popup Layer Puzzle

Tags: blackberry

I come from blackberry support forum, and got to solve this soon. any tips will be great.

I wanna a layer overlay in main UI which will not obtain all focus, ie, click volume button to open then click again to close. Just like opera's swipe out menu.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Popup-Layer-Puzzle/m-p/1403821#M181020

Comment: I read your post in the forum. I think it is possible to achieve what you want without using PopupScreen. Though I never tried it, what about using the paint method of the same screen where all the controls were added, such that volume button. If we just paint the volume bar (overlay) after painting all the control then the volume var will be on the top of others. We can do that after calling super.paint(..). It's just a hint. Your problem is interesting.

Comment: -1 because Stackoverflow is a standalone question-and-answer site.  You should ask the entire question here, not just provide a link to the blackberry support forums.

Comment: OK, I will do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you are expecting is not possible using `popupscreen`. How about using an approach were you do not use the `popupScreen`.

I would try to do the following.

1. In the main screen with play/pause, when the user presses on Volume button, add the volume control slider on the screen as a field rather than pushing a popupscreen.
2. When the user finishes adjusting the volume, and he presses on another button, delete the volume slider field.In this way, you have control for all the buttons on the screen.

On another note, how about just using the volume control buttons on the side?